# detect which endpoint entered our microservice in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, microservices

I am currently a bit stuck with a development I have in Spring Boot

Basically, I have 2 controllers with a different URL but they will enter the same service. Inside the service.

Depending on the URL the result is almost the same only that changes the value of 1 attribute, so it goes through the same service where there is a small condition that fills a value or another.

I modified the service passing a boolean but they do not accept it, I was wondering if there is some way to know when it is in the service by which endpoint I enter?

```
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder();
}

    
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder();
}
```

Comment: _"...but they do not accept it"_ - who exactly is "they" and why did they not accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition has some papable business logic that is relevant enough to have a corresponding Enumeration, consider creating one:

```java
enum BusinessLogic {
  PROCESSING_LOGIC_1,  // whatever names apply best to your use case
  PROCESSING_LOGIC_2
}
```

Then you would call the `updateOrder()` with the corresponding enum:

```java
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {
  return OrderService.updateOrder(BusinessLogic.PROCESSING_LOGIC_1);
}
    
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id) {
  return OrderService.updateOrder(BusinessLogic.PROCESSING_LOGIC_2);
}
```

Then in your `OrderService` you would apply the corresponding logic according to the enum value.

If this makes no sense because the concept does not match any relevant enough business logic, then I would put this logic to the `Controller` instead of the `OrderService`. If it is not that relevant and is really endpoint specific, why pushing this logic to the Service layer?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to signal your service from which Endpoint a specific function is called from.

If you have only two endpoints, then add a flag (`boolean`).

E.g:

```java
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder(true);
}

    
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder(false);
}
```

Then handle your flag in your `.updateOrder()` function.

Or if you have more than two endpoints, pass the class of your `Controller`.

e.g.

```java
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder(this.getClass());
}

    
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id) {

  return OrderService.updateOrder(this.getClass());
}
```

And then in your `updateOrder(Class clazz)` function, handle it this way:

```java
if(clazz == FirstController.class)
{
    ...
}
else
if(clazz == SecondController.class)
{
    ...
}

// and so on
```

There are endless ways to do this though... You could use `enums`, `integers`, `strings`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the cleanest solution from the point of view of maintainability, where you would have the service expose two methods like this ...

And then you use the appropriate method in your contoller

```
class OrderService {
   updateOrderOneWay() {updateOrder(); ... some custom logic}
   updateOrderAnotherWay() {updateOrder(); ... some custom logic}
   private updateOrder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you wanna to have to service with one endpoint you can use this
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {

return OrderService.updateOrder();
}

@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> completed(@PathVariable int id) {

return OrderService.updateOrder();
}

if you want to know wich call you must change variable
@PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable int id ) {

return OrderService.updateOrder();
}

@PutMapping("/orders/{id}/complete")
ResponseEntity<?> complete(@PathVariable long id) {

return OrderService.updateOrder();
}

you cant have same method with same input